# Converting table cells data to internal links in a separate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having an issue with a small project and I've been stuck for the past 3 days...
I have to convert data cells on a left column of a table in a html file into links (that will target other html files) using javascript & jquery in a separate js file. ***I am not able to edit the html file due to restrictions on the question***.

Comment: where is your js code?

Comment: i have to build my js code from scratch. tried a few stuffs but not producing anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You could access the cells with the selector `.code` and then use `append()` to put a link in there like so:

```
$(".code").each(function(i){ //find the right cells and for each one...
    var text = $(this).text(); //...read the contents...
    text = text.substring(3); //...remove the first 3 letters...
    $(this).text(""); //...remove the text...
    $(this).append("<a href='"+text+".html'>"+text+"</a>"); //...and replace with a link
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fawbkck/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a long 3 days trying to get it to work. Finally got it working. Appreciate the time taken to help a newbie like me.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solved your problem, please click the little checkmark to accept the answer. :)